# Irrational inequalities why it is not possible to square without additional condition

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Why when I have an irrational inequalities, e.g $\sqrt{f(x)}\geq g(x)$ (for real valued function), instead of an irrational equation I can't square both sides (in case of equation I would do $f(x)=g(x)^2$, not?), but I have to impose that $g(x)\geq 0$ to be able to square? Please can you explain me what is the idea in case of irrational inequalities?

Comment: Consider the case when the functions are constants. We have $\sqrt 9 > -6$ but $9 < (-6)^2$.

Comment: Ok thanks! This is a counterexample but I would like a formal explanation, rigorous by a mathematical point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are squaring an **equation**, what you are using is the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is a well defined function, meaning for each real $x$ there is one and only one real number that is called $x^2$.

In other words, when you start with

$$a=b,$$

you get $a^2=b^2$ because $a$ and $b$ are the same value by assumption, so squaring both will give the same value for $a^2$ and $b^2$.

When you are squaring an **inquality**, you want to conclude that from

$$a \ge b$$

follows

$$a^2 \ge b^2,$$

which is generally incorrect, as  player3236's comment showed. That conditions as stated is what is called increasing monotonicity of a function $f(x)$:

$$a \ge b \Longrightarrow f(a) \ge f(b),$$

and $f(x)=x^2$ doesn't have the property. Other functions, like $g(x)=2x$ or $h(x)=x^3+2$ do have that property.

Note that $f(x)=x^2$ is a monotone increasing function **if you restrict the domain to $x \ge 0$**, which is why squaring an inequality "works" if you know or assume that the smaller number is non-negative.

Comment: Ok thanks all clear! The last question: the fact that I can't conclude by $a\geq b$ that $a^2\geq b^2$, since the function square is not increasing, holds for negative value of $a,b$, but in principle if $a\geq b\geq 0$ I can square and everything works, right?

Comment: Yes. On that part of the real numbers the function is monotonely increasing, so you can make the conclusion.